# JQuery showing elements with an ambigious name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several divs generated by PHP that are set up like

```
<div style="width:215px;height:305px;background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);background-position: 0px 0px;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 215px 305px;display:none;position:fixed;top:100px;left:100px;" id="more####"></div>
```

with the #'s in id replaced with a number (there isn't always 4 numbers) and with their background-image set in another auto-generated css file. Erasing the `display:none;` allows them all to display at 100, 100 with backgrounds perfectly fine.

However I wish to create a javascript file with JQuery so that when I hover over a table row setup as

```
<tr id="yellow" class="yellow ####">
```

with the "yellow" being either "yellow", "green", "red", "alt" or nothing in both the id and class. The div with the matching number will appear at the mouse position.
If possible it'll move with the mouse until the mouse is no longer moused over the table row, then it'll hide again.

I got the code below from a previous stackoverflow question and edited it to apply to the first row of my table but it does not work. The first row is as follows:

```
<tr id="red" class="red 9776">
```

and the div is

```
<div id="more9776" style="width:215px;height:305px;background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);background-position: 0px 0px;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 215px 305px;display:none;position:fixed;top:100px;left:100px;"></div>
```

Any ideas why the code below does not work?

```
    var mouseX;
    var mouseY;

    $(document).mousemove( function(e) {
        mouseX = e.pageX; 
        mouseY = e.pageY;
    });  

    $(".9776").mouseover(function(){
        $('#more9776').css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX}).fadeIn('slow');
    });

    $(".9776").mouseout(function(){
        $('#more9776').fadeOut('slow');
    });
```

As well, how can I apply the code to work for all of the table rows without having the mouseover and mouseout defined for each row?

Comment: Afaik numeric classes are invalid, they should begin with a letter at least.

Comment: @bergi while that's still best practice, it's no longer a rule in [html5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#classes)

Comment: Are the elements with the numeric classes added dynamically, or are they there on pageload?

Comment: The trs are also added through PHP.

Comment: jQuery will recognize the numeric classes, but it seems like css won't -- http://jsfiddle.net/9u6Rd/ -- otherwise your code should work with a few minor changes (using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on), and some string parsing)

Comment: There is some guidance [here](http://mothereffingcssescapes.com/) regarding CSS identifiers.  You can't start with a number in CSS so it needs to be escaped, which gets ugly quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As cincodenada said, it's preferable to use the data attribute to store the IDs. I made a quick example:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr data-id="9776">
        <td>asf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="9777">
        <td>asf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="9778">
        <td>asf</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="more9776">9776</div>
<div id="more9777">9777</div>
<div id="more9778">9778</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var $activeDiv = null;
$('tr').mouseenter(function (ev) {
    $activeDiv = $('#more' + $(this).data('id')).show();
    update(ev);
}).mousemove(function (ev) {
    update(ev);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $activeDiv.hide();
    $activeDiv = null;
});

function update(ev) {
    if ($activeDiv) {
        $activeDiv.css({
            'top': ev.clientY + 10,
            'left': ev.clientX + 10
        });
    }
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/LVSzK/

Comment: Thanks for the great demo and answer! I assume that it's possible to "attach" the div to other by testing ev.clientY and ev.clientX and calling certain $activeDiv.css's based on the if statements?

Comment: @matt4682 Sorry, i don't quite understand your question. Could you clarify what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant doing something like http://pastebin.com/uw2iDKaJ to ensure that the div that appears does not get clipped by the edge of the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

As you allude to with your last sentence, the code you have will be a nightmare to scale to multiple ID's.  I'd recommend instead adding a `data-` attribute to the table rows, and then adding general event listeners to the table that takes the id from the row and shows/hides the appropriate div.  Generally speaking:

```
<table id="thetable">
    <tr id="yellow" class="yellow" data-id="9776"></tr>
    <tr id="red" class="red" data-id="8523"></tr>
</table>
```

And then:

```
$("#thetable").on('mouseover','tr',function(){
    id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#more' + id).css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX}).fadeIn('slow');
});

$("#thetable").on('mouseout','tr',function(){
    id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#more' + id).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Read up on the jQuery [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) methods for more on how the above code works.

Comment: I can't this code working, my table is <table id="list"> and I have edited the $("#thetable")'s to be $("#list"). Would me having the <tr>'s inside of a <tbody> cause the code to break?

Comment: No, as long as the tr is inside the table it should work fine.  Did you move the ids to the data elements?  Andy put together a very nice working example, compare his code and yours to see what might be going wrong.

Comment: Oh man, I feel stupid. The code had to be wrapped in a $(document).ready(function() {});